# How can I make this button stop taking up the whole width within a flex container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flex container with flex direction set to row with 3 items. I need all 3 items in a single row, with the first and last items to the far left and right side respectively, and the middle 2nd item to be centered. The problem I am getting is the button (3rd item) is stretching super wide and filling the entire width in its respective space. Any help hugely appreciated here.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.left, .right {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="center">Center</div>
  <button class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Current: [image]
Desired: [image]

What I've Tried Now:

Main Parent Div:

[image]

Button Div:

[image]

Button text is now properly located to the right side but the left padding on the button still extends out all the way.

Comment: Please [don't post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Paste it here as text. Also, there's no `.tab-sub-nav-bar` in your HTML; please update that as well.

Comment: And keep in minimal!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, your markup is invalid.  `<button>` should be lowercase and should have a closing `</button>`, not a closing `</div>`.  Once you correct that...

You can control the spacing of elements with `justify-content`.  Also, get rid of the `flex: 1;` rule as that's explicitly telling the element *to grow*.

For example:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="center">Center</div>
  <button class="right"></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the `<button>` in a `<div class="right">` and use `justify-content: end` on that:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
}

.left, .right {
  flex: 1;
}

.right {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="center">Center</div>
  <div class="right">
    <button>RightFoobarLoremIpsum</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

...or use `display: grid` and set `justify-self: end` for `.right`:

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
}

.right {
  justify-self: end;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="center">Center</div>
  <button class="right">RightFoobarLoremIpsum</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried both and the button text is correctly to the side but the button padding still extends left.
.right{
display: grid;
justify-self: end;
}

Comment: @SherbetHead Please update the question with necessary details. It's impossible to know what went wrong without seeing the code.

Comment: Updated with full code. Thank you!

Comment: @SherbetHead I mean *your question*, not *your comment*, and all relevant details, from HTML to CSS.

Comment: updated question, sorry I edited the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `flex: 1` on the two side items. Specified like that, it sets `flex-grow: 1` and `flex-basis: 0`: you are telling the two side items to grow, and not the center one.

You can either make none grow and distribute the items evenly, or make the center one grow and not the side ones.

Distribute:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.parent > * {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="center">Center</div>
  <button class="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

Grow:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.parent > * {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

.center {
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="center">Center</div>
  <button class="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

Also, your button markup is invalid: you are closing it with a `</div>` tag.

Answer (score -1):

Put the button inside of `<div class="right">`

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.left {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: left;
}


.right {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: right;
}

.btn {
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="center">Center</div>
  <div class="right"><button class="btn">test</button></div>
</div>
```